# Rails 4 render json layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to append data (e.g. `{:foo => 6}`) for all json responses so codes such as `render :json => {..}` would become `{"foo": 6, ...}`?

I tried to create a json layout in app/views/application.json.erb but didn't seem to make a difference.

The code I'm using is often similar to:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: {..} }
end
```

I kind of got it working when using a json view but it is a bit cumbersome to create a view for each response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), define a custom serializer and inherit it for the serializers for each of your models.

Say we have a `Bar` and a `Baz` model. Then we'd define serializers for each as:

```
class FooSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :foo

  def foo
    6
  end
end

class BarSerializer < FooSerializer
  attributes :id, :attr_one, :attr_two
  # ...
end

class BazSerializer < FooSerializer
  attributes :id, :attr_1, :attr_2
  # ...
end
```

This should return `{ foo: 6 }` in every response containing these models. Examples:

```
{ bar: { foo: 6, id: 1, attr_one: "something", attr_two: "something" } }
{ baz: { foo: 6, id: 1, attr_1: "something", attr_2: "something" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have layout and set common attributes. Rest you can take by parsing yield.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23496109/1123232