# Rails4 jbuilder always return status code 200, even if I put other status code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I built a json view to return json in one of ajax call in rails4 app. I have used the idea suggested here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12832116/1560470

But I always keep getting status code as 200, even if I enforce other status code.

My jbuilder view in view/managers/create.json.jbuilder looks as follows:

```
if @manager.errors.messages.any?
  envelope(json, :unprocessable_entity, @manager.errors.messages) do
    json.success false
  end
else
  envelope(json, :created) do
    json.success true
  end
end
```

My application helper lloks as follows:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def envelope json, status, errors
    json.status status
    json.data do
      yield if block_given?
    end
    json.errors errors
  end

end
```

My controller is as follows:

```
def create
    @manager = Manager.new manager_params
    @saved = ( @manager.valid? && @manager.save )
end
```

You can see even I am passing `status` params value as `:unprocessable_entity` in my jbuilder view, still response comes back as 200 every time. Even I use *any status code*, it always return 200. Status codes are defined at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: when you say `status code`, are you referring to the HTTP status code? If so, you are misunderstanding. In order for you to return JSON values, the HTTP Status Code must be 200 so that your client can receive the data. Your status goes inside the JSON block. So if you want to return an error to a client, the HTTP Status Code will be 200 and then inside your JSON block, you set the status code that you want your client to receive (500, for example, if you are returning an error). To change the HTTP Status Code, you need to use `render :status => 500` in your controller.

Comment: Yes I meant HTTP status code. If you are saying JSON response will always have status code 200, then what is the use of `json.status status` in the envelop method. And why to return it, if it does not have any significance. `json.success false` in jbuilder view can work for me to let me know the response status?

Comment: It does have significance. The envelope is a way for you, the API developer, to return status information to a client. You want the client to get a HTTP 200 OK and some JSON data (your envelope and data) so that it can then parse that response. For requests that are OK and should return data, your status will be 200 (or whatever value you and your clients agree upon). When a client passes a bad request, you again return HTTP 200 OK but in your json status you specify an error (500 or something you and your clients agree upon).

Comment: @sorens thanks for the clarification. But I disagree. `When a client passes a bad request, you again return HTTP 200 OK but in your json status you specify an error` I do think that is against REST norms.

Comment: That's up to you and your design. If you want to return a different HTTP Status Code, then in your controller, you need to use `render :status => 500` (or replace the 500 with the error code you want to use). Good luck.

Comment: @soren thanks. Per your suggestion, I added this in controller `render :create, status: :unprocessable_entity, content_type: "application/json"` but now response comes as string, not as json.

Comment: set the :content_type to "application/json". This is documented at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: @sorens If you see my previous comment, where I already have content_type set to application/json , still it comes as string.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I found success with a call to render followed by whatever status you want to issue. At the bottom of `create` put the following

```
render status: 400
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28144206/3826642

You can move the logic from that envelope method to the jbuilder template so you're passing status directly from controller to the view.

That status you have in the envelope method will only be in the json that is rendered, it's not a http response status code sent by the server whereas as the one in the render method is