# How to send http-status using JBuilder Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http-status-codes

Am using **Rails 3.0.19** and **JBuilder Gem 2.0.6** to render JSON responses.

JBuilder: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Following is the code am using to send error-messages for a specific API.

```
render :json, :template=>"/api/shared/errors.json.jbuilder", :status=> :bad_request
```

For some reason, the client receives 200-ok status. While, I have expected 400 (bad_request).

Any help, please?

Here is my code in detail:

```
  def render_json_error_messages
    #render :template=> "/api/shared/errors.json.jbuilder", :status=> :bad_request, :formats => [:json]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        render :template=> "/api/shared/errors.json.jbuilder", :status=> 400
      }
    end
  end
```

And in a before_filter method, I use `render_json_error_messages`

Comment: is errors.json.jbuilder a partial?

Comment: No, not a partial. Its a complete Json.jbuilder file

Comment: change the template route and tell if this fails.

Comment: I have changed the template URL to "/ap/shared/errors.json.jbuilder" and yes it failed.

Comment: Interestingly, even render:text=>"XYZ", :status=>400 is yielding a 200 OK status

Comment: @SatyaKalluri when you got it to fail, Did it throw a 404 error for a missing template or the 400 error you were trying to specify?

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos With wrong URL, it threw 500 error. My requirement is to send a specific/dynamic JSON for some cases. And a 400 should be the HTTP-STATUS

Comment: I'm researching and it looks like jbuilder has some issues with this. But I've never faced this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202750/rails4-jbuilder-always-return-status-code-200-even-if-i-put-other-status-code

Answer (score 19):

This works:

*controller*

```
def some_action
  render status: :bad_request
end
```

*some_action.jbuilder*

```
json.something "test"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try rendering jbuilder to string then set the status... works in Rails 4.1.4

```
jstr = render_to_string( template: 'api/shared/index.jbuilder', locals: { nodes: @nodes})
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: jstr, status: :bad_request }
end
```

Else following also works

```
format.json { render template: 'api/shared/index.jbuilder', status: 404 }
```

Comment: Thanks Girish, It still sends 300 OK in on my Rails 3.0.9. Could you give it a quick trial on this Rails version. BTW, I have this render-code in BeforeFilter, i that could give you any hint on the issue.

Comment: It ain't working Girish. At the bottom of my question, I have updated my code. Please, lemme know if it helps.

Comment: @SatyaKalluri do you see "Filter chain halted as :render_json_error_messages rendered or redirected" in the logs??

Comment: Absolutely none @girishso

Comment: created a rails 3.0.19 project... it works as expected with before_filter https://github.com/girishso/checkjson curl -i 127.0.0.1:3000/nodes.json

Comment: Thanks @girishso. I will try this out. I now have to agree, there might be some other code/lib/Gem that's overriding this setting. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Rails 3.0, but I was able to provide the appropriate status by simply adding a `respond_to` block to the controller action. As an example, I have an `create` like so:

```
def create
  # ... create logic

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {
      render status: :created, success: true
    }
end
```

The above code sets my status code to 201 and renders `app/views/orders/create.json.jbuilder`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe reverse the thinking:

```
@pictures = ...
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json do 
    if @error.present? # @error contains some error message
      render json: @error, status: :unprocessable_entity
    else
      render template: 'api/shared/index.jbuilder'
    end
  end
```

api/shared/index.jbuilder

```
json.array! @pictures, :id, :filename, :width, :height
```

works in Rails5.1.4